# Is what is happening in the courtroom known outside the courtroom in real time?

Tags: plot-explanation, continuity, bull

In the TV show ***Bull***, sometimes during the courtroom scenes something will happen and then the scene will cut away to some people who seem to be watching the events in real time and evaluating the impact they are having on the outcome. I have only seen the show a few times, but I gather that these people are involved in some aspect of juror selection, but I don't understand how they can do "play-by-play" analysis in real time. The courtroom doesn't seem to have any cameras or live reporting, and I can't imagine that they are using surveillance "bugs".  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jason Bull's company `TAC` is involved in jury selection before the trials begin, where Bull's psychology training is used to try and select jurors who will be sympathetic to their course of action.  They have people in HQ who do background checking of the jurors to try and provide additional cover to the information Bull observes.

Jason Bull has an earpiece through which he can communicate with Marissa/the rest of the team back at HQ, which allows them to stay in contact and share information/feedback on reactions from the potential jurors.

One of the other premises of the show is that TAC employs a "mirror jury" for actual trials, which is a panel made up of people who work similar jobs, have similar backgrounds, similar viewpoints and outlooks as the actual jury.  The mirror jury is usually sat in the courtroom so their reactions can be monitored from TAC HQ.  The idea is that if the mirror jury are being convinced, since they are presumed to be essentially the "same" as the actual jury, then the actual jury are convinced.  This gives the TAC analysts metrics on which jury members are possibly being convinced and which are not, which allows them to tailor their approach.